# In ASP .NET Core Razor Pages, how do I properly present server responses to the user?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, model-binding, razor-pages

Recently I have started to deal with dynamic content in my `RazorPages` web application. I found out about `AJAX` and have started to incorporate it into my application since it helps me display information to the user. For example, when a user presses a button, some information is taken from an input field and sent to the server, as usual. I use the server response (`OnGet` or `OnPost` return value) to display information to the user without them reloading the page.

However, I cannot figure out how to incorporate model binding into this. When I use `AJAX` I can build the message myself but the model binder of `RazorPages` was made to this automatically - which is great and I use it a lot, but how can I access the return value of my `OnGet` or `OnPost` when I created a form and used tag helpers to allow model binding? I know that I can return `Content(string)` in these methods but that will show an empty page with the string I return, of course.

My question is: How can I access such a string to display it to the user? Am I even on the right track here or is there maybe a better way to solve this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out some of the Razor Pages tutorials as they cover the basics of posting form data using Razor pages:

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms

Best of luck on your programming journey.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. This page you linked has been one of my main resources, however it did not cover the question that I had - or I could not find that topic, at least. Anyway: I found a solution for my problem with this jQuery plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/